# How to get database size in SQLyog

Tags: sqlyog

Other than using MySQL Workbench, or PHPMyAdmin, or mysql syntax. Is there a way I can look at the database size in SQLyog?

I'm appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT 
table_schema AS 'Database Name',
ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) AS  "Size In MB" 
FROM information_schema.tables 
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Comment: It's works perfectly, Thank you so much Asgar, I appreciate the helps.